# How is splitting performed on free list nodes for memory allocation?

Tags: c, memory-management, x86

Does anybody know how splitting a free node for allocation works? Refer to the following image, this illustrates a malloc(100) call sequence in memory:

[image]
There seems to be some magic happening here where the 8 byte free list header block is being moved 108 bytes "down" the free space, to allow for the allocation to take place "above" it. My textbook doesn't seem to mention exactly how the free space is split.

The only way I can think of this being possible is if the free space header is moved 108B (100B + 8B allocation header). After this, the original free space head pointer becomes the header pointer for the 100B allocated space, and 8B is added to that pointer to give the actual pointer to the allocated space, which would finally then be returned to the call to malloc. Seems like this would also have good efficiency too since only 8B needs to be moved per allocation.

**Question**

My book mentions a split operation is performed on the free space, but obviously that cannot be done "for free" since there is a linked list header on top of the actual free space.
How is this handled? Are the headers/pointers shifted in a fashion similar to what I described? Or in other words, is my rendition a correct possibile description of what happens with splitting free space?

Comment: There are many ways allocation can be handled.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @supercat I am aware there are allocation strategies, this question does not concern that. My book mentions a split operation is performed on the free space, but obviously that cannot be done "for free" since there is a linked list header on top of the actual free space, so the question is: how is this handled? Is the header moved to allow for allocation? I cannot define it too clearly since this is a little abstract by nature, will add to the OP.

Comment: Some systems use a doubly-linked list, but some use a singly-linked list along with a pointer to the start of memory.  When visiting each node, the allocator can check whether the succeeding node has been freed and, if so, add the size of the next node (including the header) to the present node.  When searching for free space, if the next-block pointer reaches the end of memory, it needs to set a flag and start at the beginning (if it reaches the end a second time, it should give up).

Comment: @supercat I think you described coalescing of free space, where a doubly linked list would help with freeing up free space if the previous/next blocks of contiguous memory are free in the call to free(). This question concerns essentially the opposite of that, how does the free list get "moved" to compensate for the head-pointer based allocation strategy that is shown in the figure?

Comment: If a free block is large enough to satisfy an allocation and have room for another block header (and maybe space thereafter), simply add the size of the block (including header) to the previous next-block pointer to find where the new free block should begin.  If the new allocation would use up almost the entire free block, enlarge it to use the whole thing and advance the next-free-block pointer to the next block marker (if any) or reset it to the start of heap otherwise.

Comment: @supercat My understanding of what you said: the free block header is indeed moved down by the amount of bytes that was successfully allocated by means of some sort of copy or move operation with the pointer for the new head calculated by adding the newly allocated space offset. In whatever order, the old free list head pointer is then replaced with a new header describing the now-allocated space? Does this sound right?

Comment: The header isn't typically "copied"; instead, a new one is written from scratch, but that's the basis idea.